# Alamofire 5: RequestTaskMap fatalError when app is in foreground

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am updating my project for Alamofire 5.0 and I'm receiving a crash when app is already in the foreground (contrary to [similar issues onGithub](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20RequestTaskMap)):

```
.../Pods/Alamofire/Source/RequestTaskMap.swift, line 115
Fatal error: RequestTaskMap consistency error: no events corresponding to task found.
```

I am using multiple managers to handle self-signed certificates to URLs I know only at runtime (limitation of external API). I instantiate one manager per this url and keep them in memory not to create a new one each time. Why is my app crashing now?

My setup code:

```swift
public final class ServerConfiguration {

    typealias JointSessionManager = SubSessionManager & Alamofire.Session

    enum ManagerType: Equatable {
        case first(url: String)
        case second(url: String)
    }

    public static var shared: ServerConfiguration!

    private var managers: [JointSessionManager] = []

    func sessionManagerFor(_ type: ManagerType) -> JointSessionManager {
        if let existing = managers.first(where: { $0.type == type }) {
            return existing
        } else {
            let newManager: JointSessionManager
            switch type {
            case .first(let url):
                newManager = FirstSessionManager(url: url, secret: "superSecret")
            case .second(let url):
                newManager = SecondSessionManager(url: url)
            }

            managers.append(newManager)
            return newManager
        }
    }
}

protocol SubSessionManager {
    var type: ServerConfiguration.ManagerType { get }
}

final class FirstSessionManager: Alamofire.Session, SubSessionManager {
    let type: ServerConfiguration.ManagerType
    init(url: String, secret: String) {
        self.type = .first(url: url)

        let serverTrustManager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: [url: DisabledEvaluator()])

        super.init(session: Session.default.session, delegate: Session.default.delegate,
                   rootQueue: Session.default.rootQueue, interceptor: FirstRequestAdapter(secret: secret),
                   serverTrustManager: serverTrustManager)
    }
}

final class SecondSessionManager: Alamofire.Session, SubSessionManager {
    let type: ServerConfiguration.ManagerType

    init(url: String) {
        self.type = .second(url: url)
        let serverTrustManager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: [url: DisabledEvaluator()])

        super.init(session: Session.default.session, delegate: Session.default.delegate,
                   rootQueue: Session.default.rootQueue, serverTrustManager: serverTrustManager)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the crash, it would be better to report this as a bug on [our GitHub](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) with the full crash stack. If you have a project which replicates the issue we'd appreciate it. At the least, the code from where you're creating requests may help the investigation.

However, your usage of `Session` like this is not doing what you think it's doing. First and foremost, the code you've posted shows you using the same `Session.default` instance for all of your requests, which doesn't seem to be your intention. Second, this instance is immutable, so you can't change anything about the server trust manager after the instance is created.

If you want a custom `ServerTrustManager` to handle dynamic rules at runtime, I suggest you subclass `ServerTrustManager` with the appropriate methods and threadsafety and use an instance of it with a single `Session` instance, instead of multiple `Session` instances.